# How to strongly fix N-type connector to thick RG cable?

Tags: rf, soldering, cables

Can someone tell me what kind of solder or conductive hardening paste is used here to fix the inner conductor of the cable to the pin. I tried soldering of the pin to such cables with tin, but this does not stay fixed when applying stronger tension to the RG cable and the rf-matching box is not able then to match impedance.

This solution (silver like glue from inner conductor to pin) looks professional und not soldered, but what is used here and is there a good tutorial?

[image]

Comment: You did bad soldering, that's the cause it popped off. If you want true professional, then use crimping tools.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I tried to use crimp connetors but have to say when bending such thick 8-10mm RG cables the crimping is not stable enough. In best case there is no tension on the cables and I already use 90° N-type connectors, but some force on the pin I cannot avoid in our setup. The soldering in the image is not done by me, but I want to know how this was done, as this is more professional/stable than crimping and the whole connector is a screw type like here:

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.fccps.cz%2Fdownload%2Fadv%2Ffrr%2Fcoax_conn%2Fold%2Findex.htm&psig=AOvVaw04vbT1iscvgJ4aO-3Enb0e&ust=1595881038706000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCPCFmYXe6-oCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAF

Comment: The cable on the picture is soldered without any special paste or magic, simple soldering. As for your use of cable: you have to know that not any cable may be bent with small radius, you do make a relief loop instead. And: soldering is not professional, crimping is.

Comment: It looks to me like the braid shield pulled out ot  the connector.  I don't see any problem with the soldering of the center contact, but if the braid is torn out of the connector, the center contact will certainly be pulled back too.  Show a picture of the connector, and show how the braid is handled. Proper termination of the braid in the connector is important!

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I use soft tin solder and there is no way to get it as smooth and thin like this. Is special solder equipment or solder paste necessary to do so maybe? You have a good video tutorial link maybe? Thanks in advance

Comment: @PeterBennett this is not an issue, I have to remove the insulation and shorten the center contact anyway, therefore I want to know how to fix the center pin as strong as on the image, with a normal solder stick and tin solder I cannot manage to achieve this, the slightest force will separate pin and center cable, that's my problem

Comment: an answer with a tutorial link or short description and i accept as solved

Comment: I use paste solder, a hot air gun and a soldering iron to solder center pins in coax connectors (for connectors that do not allow crimping).  Fill the pin with paste, apply extra to the wire near the pin, heat up the pin and conductor, then hit it with a hot iron and some additional solder to complete the joint.  This helps to produce a good joint without getting solder on the outside of the pin, which usually prevents assembly of the connector.

Comment: @DeanFranks thanks paste as answer and I acvept

Comment: I agree with crimping as the best solution, but careful soldering will be OK in most applications. That photo looks strong but it's a real mess, solder on the outside, almost reaching the slit in the contact. You need a small, powerful iron, and some very thin solder. It should be possible to solder the centre pin on without any solder spreading onto the outside like that. Your 10th connector will be better than your 1st, and your 100th better still. BUT the inner does not contribute to the pull-out strength of the connector! That's up to the braid, which must be properly restrained.

Comment: @tomnexus It's nice soldered, perhaps the lead could be left shorter. The solder is spread outside because there is a hole in the contact, it is used to fill the tin inside when you solder, therefore some leak is inevitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use paste solder, a SMD rework hot air gun with a small nozzle and a soldering iron to solder center pins in coax connectors (for connectors that do not allow crimping).

Fill the pin with paste, apply extra to the wire near the pin, heat up the pin and conductor, then hit the conductor (not the pin) with a hot iron and some additional solder to complete the joint. This helps to produce a good joint without getting solder on the outside of the pin, which usually prevents assembly of the connector